# Could sci-fi tech be created to track you by your microbiome cloud?

Tags: biology, technology, science-fiction, future

I have a sci-fi story set in the future and was thinking about search dogs and how they track you and then thought about having my character use technology that can see your unique microbiome cloud and track you.

So does it make sense that futuristic tech used by bounty hunters and cops and others follow your microbiome cloud where you can see it onscreen on a device, or maybe on a heads up display on goggles, etc, as colors going down hallways, sidewalks, and everywhere you go, like search dogs?

Comment: "unique microbiome cloud" - what it is? if you mean bacteria and microorganisms that exist on the you, then it is difficult for me to call it unique, as well as something permanent, whole and unchanging

Comment: Yes, however every one of our microbiome cloud is individual and are all different, like fingerprints. So people can tell whose microbiome cloud was just in a room, because no two microbiome cloud are the same.

Comment: They're just microorganisms - also they are biomes too -     
 that mean they are permanently changing and acting . And they don't even live inside in the body. In general, I don't believe in it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If in your world characters can use technology to differentiate between different people's microbiomes, the authorities will definitely use it to track and monitor everyone.

The cool thing about sci-fi tech is that *in your world* you can create whatever technology you want.

You effectively described what dogs already do, just better, and with some cool cyber gadgets associated with it. Detecting, and tracking humans based on their unique biology. No-one is going to batt an eye if your sci-fi cops use microbiome fingerprinting, and trace detection to track down your hero. Unless your readers are experts studying the human microbiome, and you attempt to shoehorn in a lengthy description of how your tech functions that kills the flow of the narrative it will work out fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact, you could already do that right now to some extent.
(https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/323127#Surprising-differences)
This article talks a bit about how every person essentially has an entire "cloud" of bacteria and microorganisms around themselves, and that these "clouds" are vary greatly from person to person.

For your story you could use some device that can detect all of these micro-organisms. There are already similar bacteria detection devices on the market today that are small enough to be hand-held, for your universe you could invent a detector that maybe has an uplink to a computer/supercomputer to analyse each of millions of organisms and use this "profile" to match against people. You could use this to figure out if someone has been at the scene of the crime, maybe even the amount of time they were present based on Bacteria culture growth (or the absence of)on the scene. You could make an entire database of profiles of known criminals (or mandatory profiling of all citizens if you want to get dystopian) that can be checked against.

I am not a microbiology expert, but I hope this helps/gives you some ideas!